# REST API for driving distance?

Tags: api, maps

Is there a service that will give me the driving distance between two addresses? Apparently Google Maps API requires you to display a map, which I don't want to do (on that particular page), and I'd like to just snag the data and save it to my DB after a user submits a form, rather than waiting for JS to do it's thing.

---

If it's relevant, this is going into a Django app. I discovered that [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/) offers a Python API, which is nice, except their latest dev release has a bug in it (can't use the API object), but more importantly, it's support for Canada is awful (couldn't find directions from any major city around here!).

Answer (score 9):

MapQuest's Directions API is HTTP Querystring based (I'm not sure if it's entirely RESTful). Can get XML or JSON response. Just need to send it an HTTP GET Request.

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/directions-service

Use the "distance" response parameter.

Comment: Wish I could switch the check over to you...this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: just helpin' a fellow Canuck out!

Comment: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/directions-ws (updated URL)

Comment: Does this still not breach MapQuest's terms? Their terms are impossible to understand.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have a high enough reputation on SO to comment on an answer but I just wanted to be clear that contrary to the voted correct answer, Google Directions API has to adhere to the Google Maps API. If you scroll down the supplied link, you will see:

> Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited. Additionally, calculation of directions generates copyrights and warnings which must be displayed to the user in some fashion. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be possible to use Google Maps `GDirections` object? This can return the textual directions instead of the map overlay if called with a div object. From there you can use the `getDistance` (or `getDuration`) functions. You can always use an invisible div for the returns if you don't want anything to be displayed on the page.

Start here
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/directions-advanced.html
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections

And use this sample code

```
   var map;
    var directionsPanel;
    var directions;

    function initialize() {
      directionsPanel = document.getElementById("route");
      directions = new GDirections(null, directionsPanel);
      GEvent.addListener(directions , "load", onGDirectionsLoad);
      directions.load("from: 500 Memorial Drive, Cambridge, MA to: 4 Yawkey Way, Boston, MA 02215 (Fenway Park)");
    }

    function onGDirectionsLoad(){ 
      alert(directions.getDistance().html);
    }
```

Comment: "Google Maps API requires you to display a map, which I don't want to do (on that particular page), and I'd like to just snag the data and save it to my DB after a user submits a form, rather than waiting for JS to do it's thing." -- Requires, as in, their policy dictates. It's not a programmatic problem, it's a legal issue. Secondly, I'd prefer a non-JS solution as I indicated. Thanks though.

Comment: Well the "requires" map you should check into. Their API docs and online examples clearly explain how to NOT show the map for customers that don't want it (the null param in the GDirections constructor).

As for calling it from the server instead of the client - just write the JS and call it from the server in a web control (not sure what that is in Django) and parse the return directly. Puts the traffic on your server instead of the client. Not sure if you can do that with a direct call though - probably have to use JS in a server web control.

Comment: Can't remember where I read it's against their ToS now. Putting the JS into a web control on my shared server might be tricky...

Comment: Check it out. I saw where you aren't supposed to save any data for offline use (which would kill your saving into a database idea) but maybe there are exceptions or loopholes. Did you try the other "big" ones? MS/Bing or MapQuest? MapQuest has server side libraries (C++/C#/Java) but I don't know their ToS.

Comment: For clarification on usage of the Google Maps API, ask over on the official Group: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

1. Signup for Mapquest Developer network.
2. Get AppId
3. Open your command shell and run the following command(or use fiddler) But running it through curl will give you flexibility to automate your request

   ```
   curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{locations: ["Salt Lake City, UT","Ogden, UT",],options: {allToAll: false}}' http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/routematrix?key=YOURKEYGOESHERE >> distance.txt
   ```
4. Save above command with all your destinations into batch or sh file.
5. Now grep and parse out your distance.txt file for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

There are free services out there, but the quality of the data may be questionable/non-existent in areas. Be aware of licences on the data too, storing in your own DB may be a breach.

http://openrouteservice.org/

Comment: Is that service for the UK only? Doesn't seem to recognize any Canadian locations...

Comment: Europe data.

More info: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/index.php/OpenRouteService. Plus other examples, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS, http://www.yournavigation.org/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Navteq.  I used their service in developing a driving directions application about 5 years ago, and got good results.  Can't speak for them lately though.  I believe the best URL is [Navteq Routing Service](http://www.nn4d.com/site/global/build/web_services/routing/map24routingservice/map24routingservice.jsp)

Comment: correct, its not - didn't know that was a requirement... sorry

Comment: I guess I didn't specify. Too early in the project to start dishing out $$$ for "nice to haves".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new Google Directions API directly, without using any javascript.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: When was this released? Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It was released at Google I/O 2010: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/directions-web-service-arrives-at.html

Comment: Unfortunately, using the service as described violates the terms of use outlined on the page: "Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited. Additionally, calculation of directions generates copyrights and warnings which must be displayed to the user in some fashion. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions." I'm running into issues because of this

Comment: @Mark Please remove the correct answer mark to this one, because the latest TOS shows clearly that is not an option anymore...