# Distance API for big volume of data

Tags: api, maps, bigdata, driving-distance

I'm looking into getting the driving distance between a current address (entered by a user) and the locations of some shops in the city / town of the user. The list of shops locations could get really big, up to thousands. Do you have any idea what are the best APIs I could use for this, that would support a volume of data this big? 
I was thinking about Google MAPs for Business Distance Matrix, but it seems to support 100000 elements per day and I don't think we fit this limit. MapQuest Enterprise Edition, Route Matrix is also an option, but this says that it might have limitations to prevent service degradation. 
I was wondering if anyone used any of these and could give me a feedback or if you have other suggestions? I'm open to paid or free products.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST API for driving distance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293689/rest-api-for-driving-distance)

Comment: Not really, I'm actually looking for a solution that supports a big volume of data. Google API even the business edition has limitations that are too strong for us

Comment: Yes really, There are more solutions in that question then just gmaps. Mapquest, Navteq and openrouteservice.

Comment: Btw, you can purchase additional quota or narrow down queries. If i want to find a shop near me. I don't need to know distance of all 100.000 shops. But just shops in my state, province, county. etc etc.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think Navteq or Opqnrouteservice support some sort of distance matrix, and getting the directions / rout for each pair seems like a lot. Regarding MapQuest, I mentioned that as well, I was more interested in getting some feedback about that. I'm only interested in the shops in the specific town of the user, but those could be a lot (like 1000) and for 100 users that crosses the daily limit for gmaps. But thanks for the additional quota tip for gmaps.

Comment: Best thing you can do is narrow down queries and only expand your search / queries on request. For example If I want to find shops near me, narrow down on my city. when I scroll down you send another request for county, further down state, etc etc. You should try to keep requests as low as possible, before looking for a service which  offers really large quotas. This is expensive, and it's better to find out how many request you actually make (by using gmaps distance free).